# Android: Map is not loading after switiching the network connectivity on an off

Tags: android, android-maps

As i started the app, map is loaded fine. Now I stopped the network connection, slided few screens and again started network connection. Now when i sliding screens I am getting a NullPointerException. The map is not able to load when onResume is called.

In onCreate I am doing like this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.cityattractions);
        Utils utils = new Utils();
        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
             finish();


            if(utils.getUserAcceptance(this)){
            utils.cleanUpSession();
            activity = this;
            context = this;
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
            utils.loadStartUpInfo(this);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            String moduleName = null;

            MapView mapView = (MapView) activity.findViewById(R.id.defaultmapView);
            mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (b != null) {
                moduleName = b.getString("neighborhood");
            }

            MenuUtils menuUtils = new MenuUtils();
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.custom_menu)).setOnTouchListener(new OpenPopup(this));
            if (moduleName != null && moduleName.equalsIgnoreCase("myneighbor")) {

                setMyNeighborHoodLocation();
                new Utils().loadCityNames(activity, -1, -1, -1, null, 0, true);
                new MapUtils().drawMap(this);
            } else {

                manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                listener = new ManageLocation();    
                listener.setSucessCallBack(this, "setLocation");
                listener.setFailureCallBack(this, "setNoLocation");

                manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        utils.getCurrentPlaceLocationProvider(manager), 0, 0,
                        listener);
```

And in onResume I am doing as below

```
protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        Utils utils = new Utils();
        if (new Utils().isConnectionAvailable(activity)) {  
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                utils.getCurrentPlaceLocationProvider(manager), 0, 0,
                listener); }

                    new MapUtils().drawMap(this);
                }
```

I tried unregister LocationListener in the onPause() method. But nothing seems to work.
Can someone point me in right direction?

here is my logcat

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 18:41:02.013: E/AndroidRuntime(32082):    at org.appright.mycity.maps.MapUtils.drawMap(MapUtils.java:59)
01-28 18:41:02.013: E/AndroidRuntime(32082):    at org.appright.mycity.activity.CityAttractions.onResume(CityAttractions.java:500)
01-28 18:41:02.013: E/AndroidRuntime(32082):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
01-28 18:41:02.013: E/AndroidRuntime(32082):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5280)
01-28 18:41:02.013: E/AndroidRuntime(32082):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
01-28 18:41:02.013: E/AndroidRuntime(32082):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Read the stack trace in LogCat to see what specifically is `null` that is causing your `NullPointerException`. Then, figure out under what circumstances you are not initializing that value (or, perhaps, are setting it to `null` after it having been initialized earlier).

Comment: add try catch block with NPE and in catch ahow toast or error message or what ever you want to do 
you are calling  something first before its been intilaized

Comment: edit your question and post the stacktrace of the NullPointerException

Comment: @endian i edited my question with logcat

Comment: @teekib can you post you MapUtils.java code too?

Comment: @endian  here is my MapUtils.java  http://pastebin.com/sWVe3JTY...getting error at line 14

Comment: @teekib line 14? your logcat tells me that the error occurs on line 59

Comment: If your error really occurs on line 14, than your `mapView` object is null. So check if `activity.findViewById(R.id.defaultmapView);` returns null.

Comment: @endian i removed the imports so u see line diffrece...in pastebin code it is line 14 at mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and in my city class getting NPE error at this line  new MapUtils().drawMap(this);

Comment: yeah but when it is first calling oncreate mapView  is not null, iam getting the map, only at onresume() the mapview is getting null..how to solve the onresume???